# JavaFX Directory Chooser - How to get the path from directory?

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, directory

I would like to get the path from an Directory with the DirectoryChooser. My code looks like that:

```
DirectoryChooser dc = new DirectoryChooser();
dc.showDialog(stage);
File f = dc.getInitialDirectory();
String s = f.getAbsolutePath();
System.out.println(s);
```

But that doesn't work, can somebody help me? The method getInitialDirectory() is always null

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/DirectoryChooser.html#showDialog-javafx.stage.Window-

Comment: I already wrote my code in the question

Comment: I thought you said you had tried the method in the linked documentation?

Comment: Did you even read it? "`public File showDialog(...)` ... **Returns:** the selected directory."

Comment: I thought he meant the method getInitialDirectory() because the window scrooled down so I didn't recognized the showDialog() method, it work's now so thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It Should look something like this:

```
DirectoryChooser directoryChooser = new DirectoryChooser();
File selectedDirectory = directoryChooser.showDialog(stage);

if(selectedDirectory == null){
     //No Directory selected
}else{
     System.out.println(selectedDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

more here: [example of DirectoryChooser](http://java-buddy.blogspot.cz/2013/03/javafx-simple-example-of.html)